# SQL query to add temporary ID column with SELECT FROM - when reading Excel file

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

The task is to get top X and bottom X rows from excel spreadsheet with SQL query, into one RecordSet.
There's no id and no headers on the spreadsheet.

As I understand, there's no such thing as "SELECT BOTTOM x" in SQL.
I tried things like "OFFSET" and "EXCEPT" to get bottom rows, but none of these is seems working.
I guess the easiest way is to create temporary ID column (like computed column), and then get the top x with "ORDER BY ID DESC".
But I can't create temporary ID column, it seems that "IDENTITY" OR "NewID()" doesn't work too.

Just in case, the connection string is:

```
    sConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sDBFile & _
                 ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"";"
```

And I think the query should looks something like this:

```
sQuery = "SELECT F1, F2, IDENTITY(1,1) AS TempID FROM [SheetTest$]"
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try row_number function?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for responding! Yes, I did - it didn't work for me too. But maybe I used it wrong (I'm new to SQL). If you could give a short example, or a link, that would be great! row_number function should help me, if it works. Thanks!

Comment: As I understand, ROW_NUMBER works only with OVER(ORDER BY ...). In my case I have to preserve the current order of records (in order to get the last X rows).

Comment: can you please try it like

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))

Comment: Query: SELECT F1, F2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum FROM [SheetTest$]
Error message: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))'

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion:
With this version of SQL, there's no way to get top X and bottom X rows with just a SQL query. Which is very disappointing. Commands like LIMIT, OFFSET, FETCH are not working in this version of SQL. As I know, they should work in SQL Server 2010+ or something. Other options, like EXISTS, ROW_NUMBER, IDENTITY requires the selection to be sorted. So, in order to get top X and bottom X rows, the only option is to get all rows to Recordset and get required rows from there.

P. S. How can I find out what version of SQL is used in my case (with giving connection string)? And, I'm using MS Excel 2016 Professional Plus. If I know the SQL version, I hopefully, will find full documentation on it. Thanks!

Comment: MS Access ACE engine does support `TOP XX` even `TOP XX PERCENT`!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MS Access (ACE) SQL which is the engine and dialect when querying Excel workbooks does indeed support `TOP` clause for number (`TOP ##`) or percent (`TOP ## PERCENT`). In order to achieve bottom however, you need to reorder rows by some column(s).

Since spreadsheet has no ID, look for number or date fields to pass in `ORDER BY` clause. Alternatively, try adding a row number in spreadsheet with Excel VBA. Save workbook and run SQL on Excel connection.

**TOP 5**

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 F1, F2 
FROM [SheetTest$]
ORDER BY F1
```

**BOTTOM 5**

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 F1, F2 
FROM [SheetTest$]
ORDER BY F1 DESC
```

Comment: Let's say F1 is list of names. How do you get the last added names? After ORDER BY F1 you won't get any first or last records, because they will be sorted by names.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot know last records. The first code block does not need `ORDER BY` (used to mirror second code block) and will return first records as positioned on spreadsheet. As mentioned, try adding a row number with VBA loop. Save workbook, then sort desending on that field for bottom records.